# Build Go code into Shared Library that Java (no Android) can execute

Tags: java, go

I have some Go code that I want to build and execute by Java SE, not Android Java.

I have been looking at [gomobile](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile) which looks great but the shared library that is built targets ARM.

How can I either:

- Use gomobile to generate code, wrappers etc and also some how
  generate a desktop compatible Shared Object.
- Somehow create a java wrapper and also build a Shared Object that I can execute.

I also note [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y9hStonl9wpj-5VM-xWrSTuEJFUAxGOXOhxvAs7GZHE/edit) design proposal to bind Java and Go. Has this been implemented yet?